# CSS background margin not working despite using both margin and padding features

Tags: html, css

The blue and red background you see in the images is a parallax scroll background. In front of that, I would like to add text with a white background. I need the white background to have around a 150px margin on either side, so that viewers still get to take a look at the parallax background. I have tried a lot of stuff and none has worked. Any ideas? [(What it looks like now)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQczo.png) [(A crude drawing of what I want it to look like)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKq7y.png)

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Alata', sans-serif;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header {
  background: #111;
}

header::after { 
  content:'';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 50px;

  position: relative;
}

nav a {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 600;
}

nav a::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0%;

  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms
}

nav a:hover::before {
  width: 100%
}

.parallax {
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  position: relative; top: 0; left: 0;
  background-image: url('parallax.jpg');
}

.main {
    width: 50%; height: 100%;
    position: relative; top: 0; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    background-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

h1 {
    width: 700px; height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0;
    padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto !important;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Alata&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <header>
   <div class="container">
    <img src="logo.jpg" alt="logo" style="width:175px;height:140px;" class="logo">

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="my_story.html">My Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="other_info.html">Other Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="ToS.html">Terms Of Service</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
</header>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
  .parallax {
    background-image: url("parallax.jpg");

    height: 1000px;


    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
  </style>

  <div class="main">

    <h1>
      PCs Built By A Fellow Gamer
    </h1>

  </div>

  <div class="parallax"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a div for the parrelax, just add the class to body and then make the following changes to .main

**HTML**

```
<body class="parallax">
```

**CSS**

```
height: 100%;
width:50%; /** Width of your white body **/
margin:0 auto;
background-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 1);
```

You can dictate the sizes of your margin with the width rule.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. Im sorry to bother you but I am relatively new to web development and was wondering how it is I could add the .parallax class to body.

Comment: No problem, you can add multiple classes to a HTML tag  if you wanted, for example, if i made a class called .red { color:red } and i wanted to use that on the body also, you would just do <body class="parrallax red">